# Repeat a simulation with different seed values in SUMO

Tags: sumo

I want to run a particular simulation for 100 times with different seed values and get each output separately into 100 files. Although I found how to set seed value I am not sure how to do repeats. I would really appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this inside sumo, so it really depends on your platform / personal preferences. On Linux the easiest way is probably a shell script, cross platform a python script could be the best way (provided you have python):

```
import subprocess
for i in range(100):
    subprocess.call(["sumo", "-c", "my.sumocfg", "--random", "--output-prefix", str(i)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I work on windows and ended up using the following in a bat file

```
for /l %%N in (1 1 100) do (      
   sumo -c hello.sumocfg --output-prefix TIME --seed !random!
)
```

Michael's answer'd be the best.